# Closing over immutable variable and accumulate values across multiple iterations as a lambda expression - Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, immutability

WebTarget in Jersey client is implemented as a immutable object, and any operations to change the state returns a new WebTarget. To add query params to it, which is coming in as a `Map<>` the following code was written.

```
public WebTarget webTarget(String path, Map<String, String> queryMap) {

    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(this.address.getUrl()).path(path);
    if (queryMap != null)
        queryMap.entrySet().forEach(e -> webTarget.queryParam(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    return webTarget;
 }
```

The problems here is every call to `.queryParam()` returns a new WebTarget and I'm stuck at how to accumulate as the variables used inside a lambda expression has to be either final or implicitly final, without any reassignments.

**EDIT**:
Reduce may not be an option in this case, as WebTarget lack the mechanism for reduction, that I cannot get the queryParam from one webtarget and set it into another. if the WebTarget api had better support for accumulation, it could have been used.

Used [Jool](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jooq/jool) to try and leverage foldLeft which is lacking in native Java 8 API, but still hit rock bottom as WebTarget api lacked the support for it.

**EDIT2**: foldLeft is the way the go as suggested in the answer below, did write a small [blog](http://spotinstance.blogspot.in/2016/08/closing-over-immutable-api-with-java8.html) on this

Comment: Guess something like a foldLeft with an Zerovalue as an WebTarget which carries the state though the iteration might help!!! do we have a mechanism to perform foldLeft with java-8

Comment: Look at the other methods of the [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) API besides `forEach`. Another good starting point is [*Reduction*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction).

Comment: Use a plain loop? `for (Entry<...> e : queryMap) webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(...);` looks fine to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want functional approach you need foldLeft(right) or reduce.

`foldLeft` is implemented in some libraries, for example [Functionaljava](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava) and [streamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex).

Functionaljava:

```
<B> B foldLeft(final F<B, F<A, B>> bff, final B z)

WebTarget wt = wtCollection.foldLeft(x -> (y -> x.queryParam(...)), new WebTarget());
```

StreamEx:

```
<U> U foldLeft(U seed, BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator)
```

**UPD** 
stream-reduce

```
queryMap.entrySet().stream()
    .reduce(new WebTarget(), (x, y) -> { 
        x.queryParam(y.getKey(), y.getValue()); 
    });
```

Comment: if I understood correctly, StreamEx solution should be something like:

`webTarget = StreamEx.of(queryMap.entrySet().stream()).foldLeft(webTarget, (w, e) -> w.queryParam(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));`

Which has to be put inside `if (queryMap != null) {...}` branch.

Interesting technique, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ol' array trick, which is not good for anything more than a proof of concept.

```
WebTarget[] webTarget = {client.target(this.address.getUrl()).path(path)};
if (queryMap != null){
    queryMap.forEach((k, v)->{
        webTarget[0] =  webTarget[0].queryParam(k, v);
    });
}
return webTarget[0];
```

You could improve it by using an AtomicReference.

```
AtomicReference<WebTarget> webTarget = new AtomicReference<>(client.target(this.address.getUrl()).path(path));
if (queryMap != null){
    queryMap.forEach((k, v)->{
        webTarget.updateAndGet(w->w.queryParam(k, v));
    });
}
return webTarget.get();
```

Comment: Sorry, I am looking at a correct way to do it. It seems like a collect will do the job nicely.

Comment: Collect doesn't seem to be the best. I would say a normal loop is most appropriate.

Comment: If you use `forEach`, there is no need to make the `entrySet()` detour here: `queryMap.forEach( (k,v) -> webTarget[0]=webTarget[0].queryParam(k,v) );`

Comment: And as a bonus, when someone later says "hey, I can run this stream in parallel", your code will just be subtly broken and probably give you the wrong answer without any sort of warning.  Great trick!  You really put one over on that silly compiler.  Use `reduce`, that's what it's there for.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: actually, this code doesn’t use the `Stream` API, so it isn’t possible to turn it into parallel. Unfortunately, it’s too easy to turn this into a Stream API usage that looks almost the same, but is subject to this issue. As the OP states, `reduce` requires the possibility to merge two `WebTarget` instances, which seems not possible.

Comment: @Holger There's really no situation in which the one-arg array trick is justified -- and as the first commenter indicated, there are millions of developers willing to seize on this "clever" trick to "fool" the compiler, outsmarting themselves and their maintainers in the process.  (If you're going to do this, at least use an AtomicRef.)  So my comment was more "just don't do this, ever" than a comment on the particular code.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I looked into the reduce, and it appears a bit cumbersome and I didn't work out the correct way yet. I switched it to an atomic reference from an array.

Comment: @matt: either, you write `queryMap.forEach((k, v)->{ webTarget.updateAndGet(w -> w.queryParam(k, v)); });` (note the `);` at the end), or you write `queryMap.forEach((k, v)-> webTarget.updateAndGet(w -> w.queryParam(k, v));` (without curly braces). The way you have written it now, it’s invalid syntax.